# Nginx 413 - Client intended to send too large body - Node app

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, node.js

I am runing a node app on nginx under Ubuntu and I am having problems uploading a 200M json file. On my local I use nginx on a Mac and I am not having this limit issue.

I have set the `nginx.conf` http client max size to 0 and 1000M but I am still getting the error

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {
   client_max_body_size 1000M;
...
```

On the front end I use express and have done this but I am not sure if the problem is only with nginx

server.js

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: '1000mb' }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '1000mb', extended: true }))
```

/var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2021/12/20 11:08:42 [error] 5451#5451: *4 client intended to send too large body:
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you restarted/reloaded `nginx` after changing its config.

Comment: I have done `systemctl restart nginx` and  `nginx -s reload` but nothing

Comment: Then you need to check that you applied the changes to the correct `nginx` configuration file. You can check the current running configuration with `nginx -T`.

Comment: The `nginx.conf` is the global config file, I have no other settings on the local config. And `nginx -t` gives out: `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: The problem was inded the client_max_body_size on the configurarion file rather than the `ngnix.conf`